# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. at

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7

My Html code

```
 <tr *ngFor="let itemObj of mOrder;let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
   <td> 
      <label *ngFor="let f of itemObj.items">{{f.title}}</label>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

My Ts code

> mOrder: Order[]=[];

```
readOrdersFromServer() {
    console.log("readOrdersFromServer called");

    this.firestore.collection('orders').snapshotChanges().take(1).subscribe(data => {
      data.map(e => {
        console.log(e.payload.doc.id);

       this.mOrder.push(e.payload.doc.data() as Order);
       console.log("order itrems2 "+(e.payload.doc.data() as Order).items[0].title.toString());


      });
    });
  }


  class Address{
      name;mobile;address;city;
    }
    class Order{
      address:Address;
      created;
      items:OrderItem[]=[];
    }
    class OrderItem{
      action;title;fee;
    }
```

but this is showing this error

> core.js:12301 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object
>   '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to
>   Iterables such as Arrays.
>       at

When i try this code it is working

```
<label>{{itemObj.items[0].title}}</label>
```

Which means it contain value and it is an array but don't no why it is showing error

[image]

**Thank you for supporting and I solved this issue**

Comment: Please show the full component and please log `mOrder`.

Comment: updated please check it

Comment: Is it Angular 5 or 7? Please fix your tags. Plus, why don't you use async pipe instead?

Comment: What's the version of your rxjs? I'm not sure about your syntax

Comment: i am using angualrr 7

Comment: And lastly, do you get the error from the parent ngFor or from the nested one?

Comment: nested one only

Comment: if i remove nested one no error

Comment: @Midhilaj Can you console.log(`this.mOrder.items`) inside the subscribe of `readOrdersFromServer()` ?

Comment: there is no this.mOrder.items

Comment: this.mOrder[i].items

Comment: because this.mOrder is an array

Comment: mOrder: Order[]=[];

Comment: @Midhilaj then try to check if all the items are array or not inside the subscribe . use `console.log(this.mOrder)` and then `this.mOrder.forEach( x=> console.log(isArray(x.items)))`

Comment: @Midhilaj can you post the result in question ? for `console.log(this.mOrder)`

Comment: yes , but  console.log(isArray(x.items))) is false

Comment: console.log(this.mOrder)   print this [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

```
mOrders$: Observable<Order[]>;

...

readOrdersFromServer() {
  console.log("readOrdersFromServer called");
  this.mOrders$ = this.firestore.collection('orders') 
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(first());

}

...
<ng-container *ngIf="mOrders$ | async as mOrders">
  <tr *ngFor="let itemObj of mOrders;let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
   <td> 
      <label *ngFor="let f of itemObj.items">{{f.title}}</label>
   </td>
 </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Since you're not looking for the I'd of the document, I changed the method to valueChanges(). Plus, to avoid memory leaks I set a new variable called `mOrders$` which will observe for `Order[]` (and will subscribe in the template, therefore it will be completed when the component will be destryoed). In the HTML, I've added `*ngIf` to to run only when the Observable returns something truthy.

Comment: (property) OrderManagmentComponent.mOrders$: Observable<Order[]>
Type 'Observable<Order[] | {}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Order[]>'.
  Type 'Order[] | {}[]' is not assignable to type 'Order[]'.
    Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Order[]'.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Order': address, created, itemsts(2322)

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/first';

Comment: import { first } from 'rxjs/operators'

Comment: ERROR in src/app/OrderManagment/OrderManagment.component.ts(59,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Order[]>'.
  Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Order[]'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Order'.
      Property 'ndpos' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: Try to write `.collection<Order>('orders');`